# Printing char arrays from a list

Tags: c

It's been awhile since I had to deal with C pointers, and I'm having trouble with a project. Here's some example code I made to highlight my problem. I Just need to be able to add strings to the "wordList" and be able to retrieve them later.

```
// This typedef is in the header file
// typedef char Word[ WORD_LEN + 1 ];

Word wordList[ MAX_WORDS ];

int main () {
  Word message = "HEllO";
  Word message2 = "OHHO";

  *wordList[ 0 ] = malloc ( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( message ) + 1 ) );
  *wordList[ 0 ] = *message;

  *wordList[ 1 ] = malloc ( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( message2 ) + 1 ) );
  *wordList[ 1 ] = *message2;

  printf( "%s\n", &wordList[0]);
  printf( "%s\n", &wordList[1]);
}
```

Currently the words are not printing, it will only print the first letter. Any tips on where I might be messing up would be incredible. Thanks!

Comment: this line: `typedef char Word[ WORD_LEN + 1 ];` is probably wrong.  What you seem to be trying to generate is a 2D (2 dimensional) array of character)  so you might use: `typedef char Word;`  then in the source code: `Word wordlist[WORD_LEN+1][MAX_WORDS];`

Comment: @user3629249: "*`typedef char Word[ WORD_LEN + 1 ];` is legal syntax for creating an alias for a `char` array*"

Comment: @alk, but not legal syntax for an array of pointers to character arrays.

Comment: Ok, I see what your idea is ... @user3629249 However this "*`typedef char Word; Word wordlist[WORD_LEN+1][MAX_WORDS];`*" also does *not* define an "*array of pointers to character arrays*"m but exactly what the OP currently has, as `wordList`.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `*wordList[ 0 ] = malloc ( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( message ) + 1 ) );
  *wordList[ 0 ] = *message;`  1) *wordList[0] is treating the first entry as a valid pointer, however it is actually a simple char array. 2) the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1, so has absolutely no effect on the parameter passed to malloc and it does clutter the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @alk, no malloc and no pointers needed.   However, if wanting to use malloc and pointers: `typedef char * Word;`  and `Word wordList[MAX_WORDS]` and `wordList[0] = malloc(strlen(message)+1);  if( NULL == wordList[0] ) { // handle error }`

Comment: @user3629249: I know, and also never proposed any (C-)pointers ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use good ol' `strcpy`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e07908c137af183), no need for playing around with pointers.

```
Word message = "HEllO";
strcpy(wordList[0], message);

printf("%s\n", wordList[0]);
```

Or even `strncpy` as @alk pointed out

```
strncpy(wordList[0], message, sizeof(wordList[0]) - 1);
wordList[0][WORD_LEN] = '\0';
```

Comment: ... or even better `strncpy()` to svoid overflowing the target.

Answer (score 1):

`wordList` is an array of C-"string"s. So use them like this:

```
Word message = "HEllO";

size_t size_max = sizeof wordList[0] - 1;

strncpy(wordList[0], message, size_max);
wordList[0][size_max] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a `Word` is already typedef'd as a char array (C string), there's no need to use `malloc` to allocate memory  in your array. Essentially, wordList is an array of arrays and you can just copy the contents of your strings (Words) into it at the desired indices. See the below code for a working implementation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// some magic numbers
#define WORD_LEN 50
#define MAX_WORDS 20

typedef char Word[ WORD_LEN + 1 ];
Word wordList[ MAX_WORDS ];

int main () {
    Word message = "HEllO";
    Word message2 = "OHHO";

    //wordList[ 0 ] = malloc ( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( message ) + 1 ) );
    //*wordList[ 0 ] = *message;
    strncpy(wordList[0], message, sizeof(Word));

    //wordList[ 1 ] = malloc ( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( message2 ) + 1 ) );
    //*wordList[ 1 ] = *message2;
    strncpy(wordList[1], message2, sizeof(Word));

    printf( "%s\n", wordList[0]);
    printf( "%s\n", wordList[1]);
}
```

Comment: Why the complicate way using `memcpy()` *and* `strlen()`. There is `strcpy()`/`strncpy()` for this Also your code does not protect the target from getting overflowed.

Comment: This posted answer has lots of problems,  lets' just simply say: "it does not compile".  I would hardly call it a 'working implementation'

Comment: @user3629249 It compiles without even a warning for me (on two different operating systems no less). What environment are you working in? Tried Linux/gcc and OpenVMS.

Comment: The address-of applied to the agruments to the `printf()`s is wrong, indeed. The rest is okay.

Comment: @alk ahh, copied from OP, didn't even notice that. Fixed now. I compiled without `-Wall` it appears.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` are your friends! ;-)

Comment: @alk yes, I was too hasty in my compilation :)

Comment: the latest posted answer does correct the problems I saw.

Answer (score 0):

Right now wordList is an array of Word, and each word is an array of chars. When you defined  `Word wordList[ MAX_WORDS ]` the space for MAX_WORDS number of Words of size WORD_LEN+1 has already been allocated in the global section, so you don't need to malloc more space for this.

To insert the message into the word you would use strcpy (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) rather than mallocing space and assigning the message. So to insert message into wordList[0] would look like `strcpy(  wordList[0], message)`. Strcpy takes in two char * with the first being the destination of the copy and and second being the source.

Here is some example code of what you should try to do:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char Word[ 10 ];
Word wordList[ 10 ];
int main(){
    Word message = "Hello";
    strcpy( wordList[0], message);
    printf("%s", wordList[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

** To be safer you can use strncpy (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) instead of strcpy. Here you can specify the number of characters you want to copy as a parameter. All the code would look the same except you would change strcpy to strncpy and add in a third parameter of how many character to copy.

Comment: Why the casts, please?

Comment: I thought they were required but guess not. Does strcpy internally cast them, or is it never needed to cast since though they are of type Word they are just char arrays.

Comment: What does you compiler with all warnings on tells you? ;-) The moment `wordList[0]` is passed to a function it decays to the address of its 1st element, which is a  `char`, so `char*` is received by the function.